# Git checkout remote branch on unborn local branch

Tags: git

How would you accomplish this?

```
mkdir newbuild
cd newbuild
git init
git remote add origin git+ssh://user@host:22/var/www/vhosts/build
$ git checkout -b origin/mybranch
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064195/cannot-checkout-remote-git-branch/30064354

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are you trying to do here? You don't have an origin remote, so you don't have any remote branches, so you can't create a local branch based off of one. You need to either clone the remote repository, or add it as your origin remote and then `git fetch`.

Of course, the error message is completely wrong. Ignore it.

Comment: sorry, forgot to include the `git remote add` line

Comment: You can also use `git remote update` to update all remote branches for all remotes.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `origin`'s active/default branch isn't `mybranch` which is why a plain clone won't work.  It might also be easier to just do this:

```
git clone -n git+ssh://user@host:22/var/www/vhosts/build newbuild
cd newbuild
git checkout -b origin/mybranch
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that, since Git1.8.0.1 (26th of November 2012): "`git checkout -b foo`" while on an unborn branch did not say "`Switched to a new branch 'foo'`" like other cases.

It does now, see [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5956732ebb4fe38d2fb0574004efabf76a8b2d10).