# cannot checkout remote git branch

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm in a github local clone. Below is the list of branches:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  online-demo
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/online-demo
  remotes/pateketrueke/develop
  remotes/pateketrueke/gh-pages
  remotes/pateketrueke/master
```

When I try to checkout a remote branch, I get an error:

```
$ git checkout develop
error: pathspec 'develop' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I can't figure out where does that come from. I guess I've been doing such checkouts for ages. Maybe I'm missing something. Anyway, I did `git fetch`, `git fetch origin` and `git pull` because I'm running out of ideas and there's still the same error.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You don't have any local branch called `develop`. When doing `git checkout develop` and no local branches are found, git will understand that you want to make a new local branch called `develop`, based on a `develop` branch in a remote repo, if any exists. In your case, you have 2 such branches `origin/develop` and `pateketrueke/develop`, so there is an ambiguity.

You can be more explicit about it by using the following form:

```
git branch develop origin/develop
git checkout develop
```

or

```
git branch develop pateketrueke/develop
git checkout develop
```

depending on what you want.

---

These can be abbreviated as:

```
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

or

```
git checkout -b develop pateketrueke/develop
```

Comment: yep, you're right. The key here is `disambiguity`. The git error is not very descriptive in this case...

Comment: Yep, I agree that the error is misleading. I assume git does argument resolution with a certain precedence. Here, it did not find a branch so it's assuming HEAD and treating the ``develop`` argument as a path. The checkout command with a path (say, a filename) allows to put in your working tree a file from a particular sha1, refname or whatever. In this case it also fails because it doesn't find any file named ``develop`` in the tree pointed by HEAD

Comment: Strange, `git branch develop origin/develop` tells me `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/develop'.` - but the remote branch exists. [Edit]: I cloned the repo with `--depth 1`

Answer (score 16):

git checkout -b "name of branch"

git pull origin "name of branch"

Answer (score 8):

Try below commands in sequence:

```
git fetch
git checkout "your_branch_name"
```

How it works:

If your branch is new in git, fetch command fetch the names and later your can use git checkout command to checkout the branch.

To view all the branches you can use

```
git branch -a
```

Comment: Here a bit remark for others. It fetches all history `refs` of remote repositories.

Answer (score 3):

You can try checking out the full SHA commit

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to refetch using

`git fetch origin --refetch`

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and found out that it was happening because the branch_name letter case was not matching with the remote branch in the command.
`git checkout case-sensitive-branch-name`